# Search string for an English word

Tags: python, string

I am doing an experiment where I take the first 100,000 digits of Pi, and convert even numbers to 1, and odd numbers to 0.

I then converted the result (which is now in binary) to ascii.

Now I have a string, 100,000 characters long, and I want to search if it contains an English word.

I am aware of the Enhance module, but unsure how to use it in this case.

ie:

If I have a string that looks like: `"9847a89(*^&*()^#589thcsdehellosfr8e9&(*)^$f"`, I want to be able to find the `hello`

Comment: 80% of your question is irrelevant.

Comment: Actually, your string is 12,500 characters long (assuming you're using 8bits/char). Apart from that, though. Please could you share your own efforts so far to solve this, and also what problem you are having with it.

Answer (score 0):

```
> 'hello' in "9847a89(*^&*()^#589thcsdehellosfr8e9&(*)^$f"
True

> 'goodbye' in "9847a89(*^&*()^#589thcsdehellosfr8e9&(*)^$f"
False
```

If you want to check for *every* English word, the brute force solution is just to iterate over e.g. `/usr/share/dict/words` and try each one in turn. There is a faster algorithm if that's too slow, but you'll probably have to code it yourself.